# My Xcode preview is crashing when using .swpieActions on a ForEach list

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

Newbie here, both to StackOverflow & to SwiftUI.  So be gentle!

I'm writing an app that has a settings page, with a number of user settings on it.  I'm also including the functionality to save the settings in a preset, so the user can change the settings between presets easily.  The presets are held in an array of Structs.

I'm showing the presets at the bottom of the settings page using a ForEach.  Selecting a preset works fine and the settings are updated correctly.

Originally I only had an ".onMove" (to reorder the presets) and an ".onDelete" (to remove a preset) attached to the ForEach and this was working fine.

I have now tried adding ".swpieActions", so I could have "Delete" and "Update" facilities.

Here is my Preset Struct:

```
struct ShotClockPreset: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var presetName: String
    var secondsPerShot: Double
    var isTimeWarningEnabled: Bool
    var warningAtTime: Double
    var warningType: String
    var warningVoice: String
    var isCountdownEnabled: Bool
    var countdownFromTime: Double
    var countdownType: String
    var countdownVoice: String
    var isTimeExtensionsEnabled: Bool
    var timeExtensionAmount: Double
    var isTimesUpSoundEnabled: Bool
    var playerOneLabel: String
    var playerOneColorStorage: String
    var playerTwoLabel: String
    var playerTwoColorStorage: String
}
```

It is held in an array called "shotClockPresets"

And here is the section of the Settings view that shows the presets (I haven't included the whole view, as it's rather long)

```
ForEach(shotClockpresets, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item.presetName)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .onTapGesture {
        loadPreset(preset: item)
    }
    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
        Button("Delete", role: .destructive) {
            shotClockpresets.removeAll { $0 == item }
        }
        Button("Update") {
            print("\(item)")
            shotClockPresetToUpdate = item
            updatePresetConfirmation = true
        }
        .tint(.blue)
    }
}
.onMove { from, to in shotClockpresets.move(fromOffsets: from, toOffset: to)
}
.confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $updatePresetConfirmation, titleVisibility: .visible) {
    Button("Update?", action: {
            if let index = shotClockpresets.firstIndex(of: shotClockPresetToUpdate) {
                print("Updating preset \(index) (\(shotClockPresetToUpdate.presetName)) with current settings")
                updatePreset(index: index)
            }
    })
    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
} message: {
    Text("Update the \(shotClockPresetToUpdate.presetName) preset with the current settings?")
}
//.onDelete(perform: deletePreset)
```

You can see the original ".onMove" and ".onDelete" that were working.  Now I've added the ".swipeActions", I've commented out the ".onMove".

And here's the updatePreset function:

```
func updatePreset(index: Int) {
        shotClockpresets[index].secondsPerShot = secondsPerShot
        shotClockpresets[index].isTimeWarningEnabled = isTimeWarningEnabled
        shotClockpresets[index].warningAtTime = warningAtTime
        shotClockpresets[index].warningType = warningType
        shotClockpresets[index].warningVoice = warningVoice
        shotClockpresets[index].isCountdownEnabled = isCountdownEnabled
        shotClockpresets[index].countdownFromTime = countdownFromTime
        shotClockpresets[index].countdownType = countdownType
        shotClockpresets[index].countdownVoice = countdownVoice
        shotClockpresets[index].isTimeExtensionsEnabled = isTimeExtensionsEnabled
        shotClockpresets[index].timeExtensionAmount = timeExtensionAmount
        shotClockpresets[index].isTimesUpSoundEnabled = isTimesUpSoundEnabled
        shotClockpresets[index].playerOneLabel = playerOneLabel
        shotClockpresets[index].playerOneColorStorage = playerOneColorStorage
        shotClockpresets[index].playerTwoLabel = playerTwoLabel
        shotClockpresets[index].playerTwoColorStorage = playerTwoColorStorage
    }
```

My problem is that when I try to update a preset, it randomly crashes my preview and I can't figure out why.  Sometimes it crashes when clicking the "Update" swipe action on the preset row.
Sometimes it crashes when clicking the "Update?" button on the confirmation dialog.
Sometimes it crashes first time, or most times.
Sometimes it will work a dozen or more times and then crash.
And I'm always trying exactly the same update, using the same values, to the same preset, so it doesn't look like anything to do with the actual data.

I have tried it probably over 100 times in the simulator, including 50 times in a row, and it's not crashed once!

I do not currently have the facility to test on an actual device.

Hopefully that's enough information for people (and not too much)

I'm beginning to think about either removing the swipe functionality, or just leave it there as it doesn't crash the simulator and it's obviously just the preview being naff.  But I just can't help but think that the preview SHOULD work too?

Any ideas anyone?

### ** EDIT **

As suggested by @Yrb, I have cut unnecessary code out of my project to provide an MRE, to see if he gets the same issue.
Weirdly, when I copied my code over to a new project, the crash always seems to happen second time I click on the "Update" swipe section, where it happens randomly in my original project.

Doing this has allowed me to find what is causing the crash, but I have no idea why.  It seems like a SwifUI bug to me, as I can't see why the offending line of code would cause this to happen?

I've put a comment in the code to show that if you remove the line:

```
.toolbar { EditButton() }
```

then the crash seems to go away (clicked on the swipe action 30 times and no crash)

Here is the slimmed down code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    
    struct ShotClockPreset: Identifiable, Hashable, Encodable, Decodable {
        var id = UUID()
        var presetName: String
        var secondsPerShot: Double
    }
    
    @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
    @State var updatePresetConfirmation: Bool = false
    
    @State var shotClockPresets =
    [
        ShotClockPreset(
            presetName: "International Rules",
            secondsPerShot: 45
        )
    ]
    
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                ForEach(shotClockPresets) { item in
                        Text(item.presetName)
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                        Button("Update") {
                            updatePresetConfirmation = true
                        }
                        .tint(.blue)
                    }
                }
                .confirmationDialog("Are you sure?", isPresented: $updatePresetConfirmation, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                    Button("Update?", action: {
                        print("Updating preset")
                    })
                    Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
                } message: {
                    Text("Update the preset with the current settings?")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Shot Clock Settings")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            //  If you comment out the line below, it stops crashing
            .toolbar { EditButton() }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `ForEach(shotClockpresets, id: \.self)` to `ForEach(shotClockpresets)`. Avoid using `id: \.self` unless you are ABSOLUTELY sure the array won't change. Your `SwipeActions` change the array, and identifying by `.self` can't handle that. You did the right thing by making `ShotClockPreset` `Identifiable`, so use that conformance and drop the `.self` anywhere you use it in a `ForEach`.

Comment: Sounds logical, so I've changed that and tested again.
Failed on the 4th attempt 1st time I tried and the 11th attempt 2nd time I tried.
It's the randomness that's bugging me - nothing random is ever easy to debug.
And it failed when clicking the "Update" swipe action, so that's before it's even trying to actually update anything.

Comment: OK so I've done some more fiddling and found that if I remove any code that deals with actual data (so the ".swipeAction" Update button code and the ".confirmationDialog" code ONLY have print statements that print plain text without referencing data in them), it still crashes randomly.
But if I remove the ".confirmationDialog" completely, then it seems to be OK (I clicked the "Update" swipe action 50 times and no crash)
So it's something to do with the confirmation dialog.
Don't know if that helps direct anyone?

Comment: This is tough to debug with out a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you really shouldn't be passing the indices like that. The problem is, as you mutate your array, or whatever Collection it is, the indices change, and are unreliable. Case in point, you delete the last element and then pass that index. If you access the array with the index, you will crash with an index out of range. Pass the actual element of the array.

Comment: I completely get that, but I'd need to post 10 different views for you to completely reproduce my settings screen.  Not sure if that's acceptable or not?
I can say that it will never send the wrong index, as it gets the index from clicking on one of the displayed elements (the displayed row), so you can only click on an row that actually exists in the array.
So how would I pass the actual element of the array? That's what I wanted to do, but couldn't figure it out, so googled how to get the element index instead.
Thanks for being patient with a novice :)

Comment: We don't want to reproduce the screen, we want to reproduce the issue or error. Start a new project, take the code that is giving you issues in there, as well as the minimal other code to run it. Then start cutting unnecessary code out while you still have the issue. You may even solve your own problem, but the key is to cut what is unneeded as it camouflages the issue.

Comment: Ah yes that sounds logical.  And I feel slightly silly for not having though of that myself.  Thank you, I'll crack on with that.
I'm doing this in bits of spare time between work, during the week, so it may be a couple of days before I get down to the nitty gritty, but as someone once famously said in a film somewhere, "I'll be back". :)

Comment: @Yrb I've edited the original post to show the slimmed down code to see if you get the same issue.  Again, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Why are you using `.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)`? There is no reason to pass this environment variable to the form. Remove that and see if you still crash. Also, when it crashes, what is the error in the console?

Comment: Removed and it still crashes.
I'm using the $editMode variable to show a "reset presets" button when in edit mode.
If the problem proves elusive, I can ditch the edit button and add an extra button in my section header to reset my stored presets.

Comment: What do you mean by the error in the console? 
A windows pops up saying the app quit unexpectedly and gives me the option of viewing a report.  Do you mean this?  There's a lot in there, including a "Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [61315]"

Comment: We need the "there's a lot in there". Grab a screenshot

Comment: Do you mean the little window that pops up to say my app quit unexpectedly, or the contents of the report it links to?  There's WAY too much in there to post in a comment and it's too many pages to grab a screenshot.  How do I provide it?

Comment: Connect your device to Xcode and run the app from Xcode on the device, and you will see the crash in the console. That is what we need to see.

Comment: I can't connect my device as the only MAC I have is my works MAC, which blocks connected devices.
And it only crashes in the preview anyway, works in the simulator.

Comment: That is something different. So yes, either provide the screenshots of the preview crash or not.

Comment: You can't post screenshots in a comment.  Shall I edit the original post and add some screenshots?  I thought you wanted me to provide an MRE so you could try it and see if you get the same crash?  Have you tried that?